# Databricks Scala : How to stream result from sql select

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub, azure-databricks

I need to send data from a databricks delta table into azure event hubs.
The data will be selected with a sql select

```
spark.sql("SELECT [columns] FROM table WHERE [where clause]")
```

This select will return many many rows and after it, I will apply some transformation (mainly to be in accordance to the event hub event data message).
At the end I will send it to event hub.

As far as I can tell, at the moment of writing, I need to use "writeStream" but is this enough? How can I control how many messages are sent per batch? Do I even need to care about it or does the lib handle it?

Another question I have is, from the moment I use "writeStream" the command hangs in a running/streaming state for eternity. Is this correct or am I not being patient enough? If I'm correct, then how can I stop it (in a non-manual way) after sending all data?

Notes:

- This will be running in a job that is to be triggered manually
- The lib i use for the event hub connection is com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.14.1

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your final records which you want to save in eventhub than after your write command you need to call .start() method which will enable your stream to write data back to eventhub.

Also if your jobs gets failed than in that case you need to stop your sparkContext using sc.stop() or spark.sparkContext.stop()